# Faster re-implementation for finding unique keys in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, key, dictionary-comprehension

I have a code snippet for finding unique keys based on their values. Such that, for all  key *s*  contained in another key *D* with the same **value**, key s is discarded/remove and key D is returned.

Input: `mydict = { 'C': 4, 'A': 4, 'B': 4, 'CA': 3, 'AB': 4, 'BC': 4, 'ABC': 3 }`

Output: `{'CA': 3, 'AB': 4, 'BC': 4, 'ABC': 3}`

```py
newdict = {}

for key1, value1 in mydict.items():
  for key2, value2 in mydict.items():
    if ((key1 in key2) and (value1 == value2)):
      if key1 in newdict:
        del newdict[key1]
      newdict[key2] = value2

print(newdict)
```

I will like to  an implementation in python 3 with faster computational time and lesser memory consumption.

Any help please?!!!

Comment: If your code does work and you "only" want improvement, consider posting it to [code review stack exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Do you require in-place modification, or creating a new `dict` is fine?

Comment: It can go either ways. The main issue get a code snippet that can do this with faster computational time and lesser memory

Comment: @JanStránský, thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is a bug in your implementation. Imagine that `mydict = {'AB': 1, 'A': 1}` and that the items are read in the written order :

- First step, `key1 = 'AB'`, `value1 = 1`:

  - `key2 = 'AB'`, `value2 = 1` we have `key1 in key2 and value1 == value2`, thus `newdict['AB'] = 1`
  - `key2 = 'A'`, `value2 = 1` we don't have `key1 in key2`, thus `newdict` remains `{'AB': 1}`
- Second step, `key1 = 'A'`, `value1 = 1`:

  - `key2 = 'AB'`, `value2 = 1` we have `key1 in key2 and value1 == value2`. Since `key1` is not in `newdict`, it is not discarded. And again, `newdict['AB'] = 1`
  - `key2 = 'A'`, `value2 = 1` we have `key1 in key2 and value1 == value2`. Since `key1` is not in `newdict`, it is not discarded. And then, `newdict['A'] = 1`.

Conclusion: `mydict = {'AB': 1, 'A': 1}` but should be `{'AB': 1}`.

To fix this, you have to sort the keys by increasing `len`, to ensure smaller keys are discarded:

```
def original_func(mydict):
    newdict = {}
    # sort by inc key len
    items = sorted(mydict.items(), key=lambda i: len(i[0]))

    for key1, value1 in items:
        for key2, value2 in items:
            if key1 in key2 and value1 == value2:
                if key1 in newdict:
                    del newdict[key1]
                newdict[key2] = value2

    return newdict
```

---

Second, the time complexity of the algorithm is `O(n^2 * K)`, where `K` is the size of the longest key. I assume that you have bigger dictionaries in your real use case. You can improve this by:

1. compare only the keys having the same value;
2. compare only the keys to the previous superkeys, not all keys;

If you have `V` different values and `S < n/V` average superkeys for a same value, the average time complexity will be roughly `O(V * S^2 * K)`. That is faster unless you are in a degenerated case.

To test this, we create a huge dictionary:

```
from random import shuffle, randint

mydict = {}
s = list("ABCDEFGHIJ")
for i in range(1000):
    shuffle(s)
    key = "".join(s[:randint(1, 7)])
    mydict[key] = randint(1, 7)
```

Then the function:

```
def new_func(mydict):
    # group the keys by value
    keys_by_value = {}
    for k, v in mydict.items():
        keys_by_value.setdefault(v, []).append(k)

    newdict = {}
    for v, ks in keys_by_value.items():
        # for each value, find the superkeys
        for sk in find_superkeys(ks):
            # and add the mapping superkey -> value
            newdict[sk] = v

    return newdict
```

Of course, the heart of the program is the `find_superkeys` function. There is no magic trick here, but you can group the keys by `len` since two keys of the same len are either equal or disjoint (maybe someone knows a faster way to do this?):

```
def find_superkeys(ks):
    # group keys by len (-len to sort by decreasing len)
    keys_by_neg_len = {}
    for k in ks:
        keys_by_neg_len.setdefault(-len(k), []).append(k)

    superkeys  = []
    for _, ks in sorted(keys_by_neg_len.items()):
        cur = []
        for k in ks:
            # keep k if k not in any of superkeys
            # by using a decreasing len, we avoid useless tests like 'AB' in 'A'
            if all(k not in k2 for k2 in superkeys):
                cur.append(k)

        # here, cur contains superkeys of a given len
        superkeys += cur

    return superkeys
```

And the benchmark:

```
import timeit

assert original_func(mydict) == new_func(mydict)
print(timeit.timeit(lambda: original_func(mydict), number=100))
# 1.6872997790005684
print(timeit.timeit(lambda: new_func(mydict), number=100))
# 0.15774182000041037
```

Comment: This solution is helpful. But you can find other solutions here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/249732/finding-unique-keys/249778#249778

Comment: @VictorAdeyemo Interseting. This is the usual space-time trade-off: the result of `all(k not in k2 for k2 in superkeys)` is precomputed. I did some benchmarks: the codereview answer wins for big dictionaries (and is even better with small keys). But for smaller dicts (around 1000 elements), my version is faster. I think you can have the best of both worlds: precompute the results as in the codereview version, and use my optimizations.

Comment: Exactly, I run the benchmark and ended up at the same conclusion.